# IIS Refuses Cookie

Tags: http, cookies, iis-7.5

I have a problem with a cookie which is not sent from the browser to the server.

After the user is authenticated, the server generate a cookie and redirect the user to the home page.
On the request to the home page the cookie header is missing and therefore, the user is being redirect back to the login page.

The web server is IIS 7.5 on Win2k8.
On the IIS, there are 2 websites points to the same directory with the same app. pool but with different host(this is only for testing purposes).

on the first site i can login and the cookie is sent and on the second one i have the problem stated above.

Any ideas why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I see this, its because the client machine which receives the cookie has a bad/incorrect system time.  Check that the client computer has a valid system date/time setup otherwise the cookie may always immediately expire.

Comment: how can you explain that it is working from host http://x.y.com but not from http://xx.y.com ?

Comment: what is the cookie domain, x.y.com or xx.y.com?  You may want to elaborate that in your question

Comment: Thanks, indeed that was the problem.